# how to access value inside a list

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i have a  model class which contain list as below

```
public class Ipcell
{
 public List<ddlCase> CaseType { get; set; }
}
public class ddlCase
{
 public string Casecd { get; set; }
  public string Casedes { get; set; }
}
```

i am passing it through ajax in view side

```
var casedetail41={};
var casedetail41s=[];            
casedetail41["Casecd"] = caseiddesc;
```

how to compare that value inside ddlcase class with value coming from view at controller

```
public JsonResult Create(List<Ipcell> casedetail41)
 {
if (casedetail41[0].CaseType.Casecd =="T")
 {
}
}
```

how to access value inisde caseType i.e i want casedetail41[0].Casecd to be compared with string "T".
but not able to reach inside that from CaseType.

Comment: `CaseType` is a list, you need to say which element you want to access before trying to access a property of `ddlCase` class

Comment: "i want casedetail41[0].Casecd to be compared with string "T"." `casedetail41[0]` will return a `Ipcell` and this class does not have a `Casecd` property

Comment: @MongZhu how to do can youu please suggest wih an ex

Comment: you need to tell us how exactly you want to compare. Do you want to compare specific items from the `List<ddlCase> CaseType` or do you want to test whether all items in this list have the property `Casecd` equal to `"T"` ? As long as this point is not explained your question remains unclear and cannot be answered precisely. Please don't let us guess.

Answer (score 0):

you can use System.Linq.

```
var res = casedetail41[0].CaseType.FirstOrDefault(r=>r.Casecd == "T");
if(res != null)
{
// logic
}
```